# Breeze + NHibernate Many-To-One Relation, avoid having to specify relation keys

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, breeze

The following many to one mapping is working (taken from NorthBreeze):

```
public partial class UserRole
{
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual long UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual long RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Models.NorthwindIB.NH" assembly="Model_NorthwindIB_NH">
  <class name="UserRole" table="`UserRole`" dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="dirty">
    <id name="ID" column="`ID`" type="long" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="User" column="`UserId`" class="User" />
    <many-to-one name="Role" column="`RoleId`" class="Role" />
    <property name="UserId" type="long" not-null="true" insert="false" update="false" />
    <property name="RoleId" type="long" not-null="true" insert="false" update="false" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How can I make this kind of many to one working (without UserId and RoleId properties specified in the model):

```
public partial class UserRole
{
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Models.NorthwindIB.NH" assembly="Model_NorthwindIB_NH">
  <class name="UserRole" table="`UserRole`" dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="dirty">
    <id name="ID" column="`ID`" type="long" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="User" column="`UserId`" class="User" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Role" column="`RoleId`" class="Role" not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Error thrown:**
Could not find matching fk for property Models.NorthwindIB.NH.UserRole.User

Could this be somehow handled in the future versions of BreezeJs, or is there currently a way of doing it without having to specify these keys in the model itself? Or is there more to it than what i'm seeing?

**EDIT (unofficial solution):**
Thank you for guiding us in the right direction. As this was something we wanted taken care of, we made some modifications ourselves based on what Steve Schmitt said.

Here's a link to the changes so you can see how we solved this issue, so it can be of help to anybody else. (please note that this code only works for NHibernate)

https://github.com/maca88/Breeze/commit/7a80c35cf0b20b5cffdef6d2eddeccd1bdeb3735

Comment: Where is your error thrown? At initial glance the mapping looks ok.

Comment: The error is thrown on metadata generation, only when using the 2nd example, because we're not specifying the keys for the relations (User and Role) in the class. I understand why there's an error, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make models without having to specify the relation keys in them as well.

Comment: Sorry I am not still 100% clear where the error is thrown. Are you saying when you build the session factory or is this a breeze error?

Comment: The error is thrown on server side while trying to generate Breeze metadata.

Comment: @RagingTroll The code for your solution is gone, the git link is dead. Could you re-post your solution as an answer, embedding the relevant parts of the code so that they remain useful to the StackOverflow community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but we're planning to fix that.  The problem, as you and Rippo have learned, is that the FKs are required on the client for Breeze to work.  They are also required to re-connect the entities on the server during the `SaveChanges` processing.

Our idea (as yet untried) is to:

1. Create necessary foreign key properties in the metadata where they don't exist in the real model.  These would be marked as "synthetic" somehow ('$' prefix, special property, etc).
2. During the JSON serialization process, populate the synthetic foreign keys from the related entities or NH proxies.
3. During the JSON deserialization process (when saving), carry the synthetic foreign key information along with the entity, so it can be used to re-establish relationships or create NH proxies.

Not a trivial exercise.  We realize that it's important for developers who have existing N/Hibernate models, and don't want to modify them to use Breeze.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Based on what you wrote, we made our own solution, which I posted on the original question.

Comment: Niiice!  Looks like you put all the pieces in place - and rather quickly, I might add.  Does it work well?  This is certainly something that others will find useful.

Comment: For the limited testing that we did on the NorthBreeze testcase, it worked great! It still needs some more serious testing before we're sure tho.. and if we run into any bugs we'll update the GitHub accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded [NorthBreeze](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/northbreeze) and took a quick look. Breeze has a notion of a `FK map` and I suspect the FK's are needed to link entities.

According to the [docs](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties)...

> Breeze associations require foreign keys.

This means that all foreign keys needs to be exposed in breeze so as to allow for navigation/retrieving related entities. In your example it most likely allows breeze to list users and their associated roles.

```
<property name="UserId" ... insert="false" update="false" />
<property name="RoleId" ... insert="false" update="false" />
```

The NHibernate mapping for these foreign keys disables these keys from changing directly. Therefore I would leave the mapping as is as it is not going to cause any noticeable impact on the code-base.

[image: Breeze meta data]

Comment: I do know why there's an error, what I am doing wrong to invoke it, and how to fix it so it will work. But all of that is not the point of my post, the point is to get AROUND having to specify the primary keys in the model itself. I am looking for a smart way to add this "feature" to Breeze, or if such a feature is to be added at a later version of Breeze by their Dev team.

Comment: Did you read the answer? I am sorry this is not what you want to hear. No its not possible as Breeze creates a FK map for navigation purposes and `NEEDS` the FK exposed in the mapping.

Comment: My answer was formed from your final comment `Or is there more to it than what i'm seeing?`

Comment: Having the FK in the metadata doesn't also mean having it in the model itself. I have made a quick hack that adds the FK to the metadata for client use, without the need of having it as a model property. But that was a hack, that would probably rise issues with other stuff down the line.. and I was wondering if somebody would come up with a better way. If not, than I'll just use the standard way of having the properties in the model and be done with it. Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough, and thanks for taking your time on it.

Comment: I suspect the NH.Breeze can't work out the `FK's` if the model does not have the `FK` defined, I suspect convention over configuration. e.g. It can't work on `UserRole.User.Id` and has to use `UserRole.UserId` as if you think about it, it is the FK!