# How to build One-To-Many relationships with NHibernate for use with Breezejs

Tags: nhibernate, metadata, breeze, one-to-many

I am trying to map a relaitively simple data model with NHibernate for use with breeze.js. The data model consists of four entities and looks like this:

[image: The Data Model]

The problem seems to be with the relationship between the `CourseDate` and the `CourseDateStudent` entity. When calling the `Metdata` method of my BreezeController I get the following error:

> **System.ArgumentException:**  "Could not find matching fk for property HR.CourseManager.Web.Data.Entities.CourseDateStudent.CourseDate"

I do not know what exactly causes this behavior as I think I have implemented my model as recommended by the [breeze.js documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/nhibernate-support).

There is [another question convering a somewhat similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22146668/1521227), but this question does not address having composite keys.

(Remark: Adding surrogate keys like numeric ids is not an option here. As you might have guessed this is not the real data model but one that simply has had its entities renamed. The underlying database is used by a whole bunch of applications and cannot be changed.)

---

**Enough of writing about my problem. Let's see some code!** So there is the `CourseDate` entity which has a composite key consisting of the properties `CourseCode` and `Date`:

- **CourseDate.cs:**

  ```
  public class CourseDate {
      public CourseDate() {
          this.Students = new List<CourseDateStudent>();
      }

      public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
      public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
      public virtual string CourseCode { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<CourseDateStudent> Students { get; set; }

      // Skipped implementation of Equals and GetHashCode for readability
  }
  ```

- **CourseDate.hbm.xml:**

  ```
  <hibernate-mapping assembly="CourseManager.Web" 
                     namespace="CourseManager.Web.Data.Entities" 
                     xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="CourseDate" table="COURSE_DT" lazy="true" >
      <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one name="Course" column="COURSE_CODE" />
        <key-property name="Date" column="DT" />
      </composite-id>

      <property name="CourseCode" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="COURSE_CODE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
      </property>

      <bag name="Students" inverse="true">
        <key>
          <column name="COURSE_CODE" />
          <column name="COURSE_DT" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="CourseDateStudent" />
      </bag>
    </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
  ```

And then there is the `CourseDateStudent` entity that has a primary key consisting of the `CourseCode` and the `CourseDate` property (thus defining the foreign key relationship to the `CourseDate` entity) as well as the `StudentId` property:

- **CourseDateStudent.cs**

  ```
  public class CourseDateStudent {
      public virtual CourseDate CourseDate { get; set; }
      public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
      public virtual long StudentId { get; set; }
      public virtual string CourseCode { get; set; }
      public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

      // Skipped implementation of Equals and GetHashCode for readability
  }
  ```

- **CourseDateStudent.hbm.xml**

  ```
  <hibernate-mapping assembly="CourseManager.Web" 
                     namespace="CourseManager.Web.Data.Entities" 
                     xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="CourseDateStudent" table="COURSE_DT_STUD_LNK" lazy="true" >
      <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one name="CourseDate">
          <column name="COURSE_CODE" />
          <column name="COURSE_DT" />
        </key-many-to-one>
        <key-many-to-one name="Student" column="STUD_ID" />
      </composite-id>

      <property name="StudentId" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="STUD_ID" sql-type="NUMBER" />
      </property>

      <property name="CourseCode" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="COURSE_CODE" sql-type="VARCHAR2" not-null="true" />
      </property>

      <property name="Date" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="COURSE_DT" sql-type="DATETIME" not-null="true" />
      </property>
    </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
  ```

Comment: Just a side note: *"...I am trying to build a simple data model..."* then I strongly suggest: do not use composite key. Introduce surrogated keys ONLY. for each entity. That will give you more sooner or later...

Comment: @RadimKöhler as I stated in question already: "Adding technical keys like numeric ids is not an option here. As you might have guessed this is not the real data model but one that simply has had its entities renamed. The underlying database is used by a whole bunch of applications and cannot be changed"

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the Breeze code that builds metadata from NHibernate models.  As you discovered, it wasn't finding the foreign keys correctly when composite keys were used.

The fix for the issue is now on [github](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net) and will be in the next release.  Sorry it took so long!